# Could somebody please check my work?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, phrase-choice

I am very new to Italian and was just posting this here to have it proof-checked, thank you!

> Questo è Haid Mahmood. Lui è mio piccolo fratello. Lui ha undici anni ma il suo compleanno è il sedici Maggio, due giorno da oggi. Lui è pakistano ma abita a Perth in Australia. Lui parla inglese e urdu. Haid è molto fastidioso ma lui è un po' amichevole. Lui non è molto alto. Haid ha I capelli ricci. Haid è molto bravo in musica. Lui suona la tromba.

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE! Normally question about translation are in general off-topic. If you could provide us the original text to translate and what you wrote in your question is your best attempt then we can help you.

Comment: @abarisone he wrote that he wrote this sentence... I don’t think it’s off topic since he’s asking if his italian sentence is correct, and he’s not asking for a translation. This is his attempt to write something in Italian, not to translate something existing.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! As you can see in [the page in the help centre describing what is on topic](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), proofreading questions ("are there any mistakes?") are off-topic here, unless the source of concern is clearly specified.

Comment: Relevant Meta discussion: https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/should-we-allow-questions-of-the-form-check-my-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questo è Haid Mahmood. Lui è il mio fratello minore. Lui ha undici anni ma il suo compleanno è il sedici Maggio, fra due giorni. Lui è pakistano ma abita a Perth in Australia. Lui parla inglese e urdu. Haid è molto fastidioso ma anche un po' amichevole. Lui non è molto alto. Haid ha i capelli ricci. Haid è molto bravo in musica. Lui suona la tromba.

That’s how I’d correct your sentence at first. Anyway, even if it’s not a mistake, I’d suggest not to repeat the nominative pronoun “lui”, since in italian it’s already expressed in the verb. So you might rather to say:

> Questo è Haid Mahmood, mio fratello minore. Ha undici anni. Il suo compleanno è il 16 maggio, fra due giorni. È pakistano ma abita a Perth, in Australia. Parla inglese e urdu. È molto fastidioso ma anche un po' amichevole. Non è molto alto e ha i capelli ricci. È molto bravo in musica e suona la tromba.

Comment: In my opinion, "mio fratello minore" could be replaced with "il mio fratellino", which is less formal; but it depends on the context where the sentence will be used.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi sure, that's a great option as well.

Comment: Would removing the "lui" pronoun be applicable even through speech or is it only when the text is being read?

Comment: Most of the time the third person pronoun is omitted in italian, especially in spoken language. All those "lui" in the text, although not grammatically wrong, make it evident that it's not something written by a native speaker.

Comment: @HamadanMahmood you can do that either when you write, either when you speak.